# Auto focus on a legend item in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We are facing an issue while implementing the legend bar in highcharts. The legend bar is scrollable with multiple legend items. Only few graphs/series are highlighted on the chart and rest are all invisible. So if there are 20 items in legend bar and only the last item is highlighted, when the chart is first accessed on browser it appears as if none of the items are highlighted as the legend would display first page by default. The highlighted item in legend would be accessible only after user scrolls to next page of the legend. Instead we would like the legend bar also to be autofocussed to that screen where there is first highlighted item.

Would this be possible

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way to do it, but you have two options:

- make sure visible series come always as first (just sort them before chart is created)
- use built-in function to scroll legend using `chart.legend.scroll(pageIndex, animation);`

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Could you please provide any template for this code so I can use this in our project

Comment: What kind of template..? Sort series BEFORE chart is created. Or use [load callback](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) to use `this.legend.scroll` (`this` points to chart).

Comment: The scrolling part works fine now. Is there a way to check each item in the legend bar if it is highlighted? In other words I think a loop is required to parse through each page of the legend bar

Comment: Try to loop through all series and check if series is visible (`series.visible` flag). It's the same as checking legend item state.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Actually I was actually able to loop through all the series. But how can I know the page number in the legend bar for the "visible" series. For instance if there are 20 items in legend bar displayed on 3 pages as 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3 . If 20th item/series is visible how can I map the series to "appropriate page(1/3 or 2/3 or 3/3) on legend bar" so I can call scroll function as this.legend.scroll(<page number>);           We have a dirty solution of incrementing the page automatically based on number of series already parsed.Is there any generic solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is no such think like connection between legend page and items in that page.. there are plans for upgrade legend, to make more responsive, like setting max number of lines/items per page etc. but that are only plans, no strict date for implementing this. Keep update with our [roadmap](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog).